# Change from Windows Import to Picasa

Tags: iphone, video, import, picasa

Whenever my iPhone is plugged in, my Windows7 laptop imports the pictures and videos from it. I want to change this to using Picasa because the Windows importer creates a folder based on the date and time pictures are imported vs. the date and time pictures are actually taken!

1. How do I change my iPhone default importer to Picasa?
2. Are there any issues using Picasa for the picture and video import?

Comment: As a reference, this question may be better suited in superuser.com because you’re likely to find more iPhone+Windows users there.

Comment: @Martín From a pragmatic standpoint yes, but as this question involves the iPhone it's definitely on-topic for this site too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Vista (and probably in 7)

1. Click on the Start button in the lower left hand side of the screen.
2. Type "AutoPlay" in the search bar and click on it when it comes up.
3. In the AutoPlay window, down near the bottom under Devices should list your iphone.  If you're using the latest version of Picasa, it'll say "Picasa3 using Picasa3" (and also choose every action you want and any application you want to be your default).
4. click save to exit.

Comment: You should mention that this answer was copied & pasted from [Google's Picasa Help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Picasa/thread?fid=16fc82228ad9eae50004630e7f1c788c).

Answer (score 1):

When you plug the device into Win 7, you should be prompted with an AutoPlay box.  Click the "View more AutoPlay options in Control Panel".  This will give you the ability to change the defaults for the device (you'll see iPhone at the bottom).  Next to Apple iPhone is a list of applications that windows will auto load when the device is plugged into the USB.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that as of the latest release (3.8) Picasa running on Windows 7 and Vista does not import video from the iPhone. It still works fine in XP.